# Showing triangulation of equilateral triangle is non-regular

Tags: geometry, triangles, convex-geometry, triangulation, convex-hulls

I am trying to show that this triangulation is non-regular (sometimes called non-convex I think). By regular I mean there exists a convex function from the triangulation to $\mathbb{R}$ such that the faces of the lower convex hull of the lifted points correspond to the triangles of the triangulation. Another definition I have seen is that the domains of linearity of the function coincide with the faces of the triangulation.

[image]

I know that the way to do this would be to attempt to construct such a function and probably find inequalities going around the triangle, thus reaching a contradiction. However, I can't seem to figure out the way to do this.

To start, I think it is possible to assume that the three inner vertices lie below the three outer vertices but I am not sure why. If this is the case then I can picture in my head how lifting up the outer vertices would cause one of the faces to not be linear but I'm struggling to see how to make this mathematical. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not following...  The figure looks like a Delaunay triangulation, which you would get if you lifted to a paraboloid.  So by your definition it is regular.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a Delauney triangulation, I have just seen it as an example of a non regular triangulation in several texts, but never with an explanation, for example page 3 of this https://www.ams.org/journals/spmj/2005-16-04/S1061-0022-05-00872-1/S1061-0022-05-00872-1.pdf

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected.  It is not Delaunay.  Is it enough to show that the triangulation is not Delaunay?  Or are you trying to show that the triangulation when lifted to a paraboloid is not convex? (Both are equivalent, so I'd want to choose the easier one.)

Comment: I've provisionally posted an answer showing that one triangle violates the Delaunay condition.  If that's not what you want we can go from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if possible I would like to show that the triangulation cannot be lifted to a convex paraboloid as I have not seen the definition of Delauney appear in the areas I've been researching.

Comment: I've added a reference that discusses the Delaunay/convex relationship.

Comment: I noticed that the title of your question referred to an equilateral triangle.  So I added a short discussion of that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### October 2023 Update:

In July 2020 I gave an answer to the above question about non-regular triangulations.  It seemed sufficient at the time, but two and a half years later [a much better answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4599626/1257) was posted.  I'd recommend reading that one first.

For background and more details on the question, see [Regular Triangulations And Steiner Points](https://www.ams.org/journals/spmj/2005-16-04/S1061-0022-05-00872-1/S1061-0022-05-00872-1.pdf), especially Section 2 and the references.  See also notes and material from [an MSRI workshop on triangulations](https://www.slmath.org/workshops/371#schedule_notes), including [this note](https://www.slmath.org//system/paperclip/documents/data/000/033/874/original/santos3.pdf) that contains a folklore answer to the OP on pg 3.

##### Original July 2020 answer:

We can easily prove that the given triangulation is not Delaunay.  The figure below show that the circumcircle of $\triangle{DGH}$ contains another vertex C.  This violates the condition of a Delaunay triangulation, which is that no circumcircle of a triangle contains the vertex of a different triangle.

[image: not Delaunay]

The equivalence of a Delaunay triangulation and a convex hull on a paraboloid via a lifting transform is discussed in Gallier and Quaintance's [Aspects of Convex Geometry Polyhedra, Linear Programming, Shellings, Voronoi Diagrams,
Delaunay Triangulations](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ejean/combtopol.pdf), in Section 12.4, pgs 332-334.  This takes about 2 pages of exposition, so I won't repeat it here.  Background, references, and associated topics are discussed in the same chapter (Chapter 12).

There's the possibility, implied by the title of the question, that the diagram is meant to be a triangulation of nested equilateral triangles.  Then the polygons $CHGD, CEFH, EDGF$ would be trapezoids, and thus cyclic.  We know that a circle lifts to an ellipse (see Gallier and Quaintance), and since an ellipse is planar, the trapezoids would lift to planar faces.  The projection back to the plane would not be triangulation and therefore (by the definition given in the question) not regular.

Comment: There are regular triangulations that are not Delaunay (in general, there is only one Delaunay triangulation of a given set of points, but many regular ones). The flaw in the logic is that convex function mentioned in the question not necessarily could be interpolated with quadratic paraboloid. Hence, I don't think that your argument is correct.

Comment: @MykolaPochekai - this is an older question and I don't remember the details.  It looks like, maybe based on discussion in the comments, and whether or not this was supposed to be an equilateral triangle, that the answer narrowed on whether it was Delaunay or not.  Unfortunately I don't have the time to closely revisit this, but would certainly be interested in whether you have an answer to the question.  Also, my experience with regular triangulations had always been as a dual to power diagrams, and I had not seen this (I presume looser) definition of regular triangulation.

Comment: Ok, sure. By the way, the question "is triangulation T regular?" is stable under affine transformations, so equilateral vs non-equilateral cannot be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Using the labels as in brainjam's answer, by contradiction, consider a function $$\omega : \{E,D,C,F,G,H\} \to \mathbb R$$  which produces your triangulation by the process which you have described. Let $\hat{\omega} : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be an associated triangulation-piecewise-linear function. We can assume $\omega(F)=\omega(H)=\omega(G) = 0$ since perturbation of $\hat{\omega}$ by affine function will not affect induced triangulation and points $F,H,G$ are affinely independent. The condition that edge $CF$ will appear in triangulation is $\omega(C)>\omega(E)$. Symmetrically, appearance of edges $EG$ and $DH$ equivalent to $\omega(E)>\omega(D)$ and $\omega(D)>\omega(C)$. So we have $\omega(C)>\omega(E)>\omega(D)>\omega(C)$ which is desired contradiction.